# getting a const_iterator from iterator

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, template-meta-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obtaining const_iterator from iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105918/obtaining-const-iterator-from-iterator)

I want to write a metafunction which returns the corresponding `const_iterator` from an `iterator`

```
template <class Iterator>
struct get_const_iterator
{
    typedef ??? type;
};
```

- `get_const_iterator<int*>::type` must be `const int*`
- `get_const_iterator<const int*>::type` must be `const int*`
- `get_const_iterator<int* const>::type` must be `const int*` or `const int* const`, I don't   care
- `get_const_iterator<std::list<char>::iterator>::type` must be `std::list<char>::const_iterator`

etc.

Can this be done with `iterator_traits` or without them?

***Edit:*** Let's assume that if 2 container have the same `iterator` type then they also have the same `const_iterator` type. I think this is a reasonable assumption, although theoretically not entirely correct one.

Comment: I don't think that the correspondence you're asking for is well-defined. In principle, although this would be a weird implementation, `vector<int>::iterator` and `list<int>::iterator` could be the same class (how's that for failing the single responsibility principle?), but `vector<int>::const_iterator` and `list<int>::const_iterator` could be different classes.

Comment: @Fred: Hmm.. the possible dupe asks if there is one, not how to write one :)

Comment: @Armen: would the practical problem be solved by a wrapper that drives an underlying iterator and constifies all references to the elements, rather than telling you the actual type used by any particular container as its `const_iterator`? In fact several wrappers, since you'd want to dispatch on the iterator tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in C++0x

```
template <typename Container>
Container container (typename Container :: iterator);

template <typemame Iterator>
struct get_const_iterator
{
    typedef decltype (container (Iterator())) :: const_iterator type;
};
```

Although I'm starting to agree with Steve -- this is not a general solution since different containers may have the same iterator types.

Comment: I think Steve's comment is pertinent here.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think @Steve's comment, theoretically valuable indeed, is more science fiction than reality :)

Comment: I think the more germane question is what purpose such a thing would be used for. Why would there be a need to figure out a const iterator from the non-const version?

Comment: @Armen: Sending men into space was science fiction until they tried it... and then a rocket blew up because somebody made a programming mistake.

Comment: If Steve's comment comes to light, then in my solution it doesn't matter which container you use anyway.

Comment: Also, this only fulfills @Armen's last requirement.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but I think it doesn't require my science-fiction scenario to go wrong. If multiple containers share an iterator, then isn't the call to `container` ambiguous, even if those containers in fact do all use the same const_iterator too? It's actually not that implausible that multiple containers would share an iterator - for example if `vector<int>` and `array<int>` both use `int*` (or the same helper class). The unlikely bit is that they would not then share a `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Martinho: to be fair, though, the part it attempts is the tricky part. From past questions I think Armen's probably up to partially specializing his struct for pointer types :-)

Comment: This is wrong on another level in that a function template of the form `template<typename T> void f(typename T::dependent_type);` cannot use deduction.

Comment: Missing `typename` after `typedef`. typo in `typename` for template parameter. But is not working anyway as @LucDanton points out. Not a satisfying answer sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the current standard, if you are willing to partially specialize for the containers, as in...

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

// default case
template <typename Iterator, typename value_type, typename container_test = Iterator>
struct container
{
  typedef Iterator result;
};

// partial specialization for vector
template <typename Iterator, typename value_type>
struct container<Iterator, value_type, typename std::vector<value_type>::iterator>
{
  typedef typename std::vector<value_type>::const_iterator result;
};

// partial specialization for list, uncomment to see the code below generate a compile error
/* template <typename Iterator, typename value_type>
struct container<Iterator, value_type, typename std::list<value_type>::iterator>
{
  typedef typename std::list<value_type>::const_iterator result;
}; */

// etc.

template <typename Iterator>
struct get_const
{
  typedef typename container<Iterator, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>::result type;
};

int main(void)
{
  std::list<int> b;
  b.push_back(1);
  b.push_back(2);
  b.push_back(3);
  get_const<std::list<int>::iterator>::type it1 = b.begin(), end1 = b.end();
  for(; it1 != end1; ++it1)
    ++*it1; // this will be okay

  std::vector<int> f;
  f.push_back(1);
  f.push_back(2);
  f.push_back(3);

  get_const<std::vector<int>::iterator>::type it = f.begin(), end = f.end();
  for(; it != end; ++it)
    ++*it; // this will cause compile error

}
```

Of course, will repeat Steve's point above, and also the requirement is that `iterator_traits` for your iterator exists.

Comment: Requires specialization for each container type, so will stop working for user containers for example.