# Check/modify iterator "constness"

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, constants

I have two and a half closely related questions. Given an STL iterator-type passed as a template parameter:

1. How to determine whether the type corresponds to a const- or non-const iterator?
2. Alternatively to 1., how to impose (using `enable_if`s for instance) that this type corresponds to a non-const iterator?
3. <s>How to obtain the const- version of the iterator from the non-const one (and *vice versa*)?</s> [ Note: answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105918/obtaining-const-iterator-from-iterator); not surprisingly, you can't. ]

***Where does this question come from:***

I wrote a small class to facilitate arithmetic/relational/algebraic operations on vectors (by vector I mean 1d fixed-size data, not the STL vectors). Instead of imposing a specific data container, I've defined an interface and derived several possible containers that are basically "wrapping" various ways of storing data. One of these containers is a wrapper for STL-iterators, and I'm having some troubles with it.

Comment: You could start with [`std::is_const<decltype(*it)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const).

Comment: @BoBTFish I tried but doesn't work. `const_iterator` and `const iterator` are two different things. Try this: http://pastebin.com/kKQEQthj

Comment: @BoBTFish Sorry, did you edit your comment? I could swear I didn't see the `decltype(*it)` when I posted my last comment.. You would be right too with this I guess :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1:**

You could use the following type trait:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_const_iterator : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_const_iterator<T,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_const<
            typename std::remove_pointer<
                typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer
                >::type
            >::value
        >::type> : std::true_type { };
```

Here is a demonstration:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_const_iterator : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_const_iterator<T,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_const<
            typename std::remove_pointer<
                typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer
                >::type
            >::value
        >::type> : std::true_type { };

int main()
{
    typedef std::list<int>::iterator LI;
    typedef std::list<int>::const_iterator CLI;
    static_assert(is_const_iterator<LI>::value, "!"); // Fires
    static_assert(is_const_iterator<CLI>::value, "!"); // Does not fire

    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator VI;
    typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator CVI;
    static_assert(is_const_iterator<VI>::value, "!"); // Fires
    static_assert(is_const_iterator<CVI>::value, "!"); // Does not fire
}
```

And here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/4v2mqi).

**Question 2:**

With the above type trait, this becomes simple. Suppose you have a function template `foo()` that you want to constrain so that it accepts only non-`const` iterators:

```
template<typename It,
    typename std::enable_if<!is_const_iterator<It>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(It i)
{
    // Does something with i...
}
```

And a simple demonstration program:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo(v.begin()); // OK
    foo(v.cbegin()); // ERROR!
}
```

And here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/HXCUYu).

Comment: I just thought about using the `::reference` typedef from the type traits too.. But your answer is impeccable! Thanks :)

Comment: Just a question: why not use `typename = typename std::enable_if< !is_const_iterator<It>::value >::type` as a "template-filter" in your example for Question 2? This is the way to use enable_ifs I've seen most frequently, but if there's something wrong with it, I'd like to know what :)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn see http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html#evolution for an explanation of how that form may fail.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Sorry, I had to leave yesterday and saw your comment only now. Basically, R.MartinhoFernandes gave you the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

For 1), you could do something like this:

```
std::is_const<
  typename std::remove_reference<
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
  >::type
>::value
```

Or this:

```
std::is_const<
  typename std::remove_reference<
    decltype(*iterator)
  >::type
>::value
```

You can use these predicates to pass to `std::enable_if` to implement 2).

**NOTE:** As pointed out by R. Martinho Fernandes in the comments, these predicates will fail if the iterator in question uses a different type than plain references for its `reference` trait (such as `std::vector<bool>::const_iterator` does).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess you were first to post the answer, and @AndyProwl has the same answer than you, so I don't know which one to mark.. Just a question: why use `decltype`?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn `*iterator` is an *expression,* but `std::remove_reference` requires a *type* (as it's a template with a template type parameter). Therefore, you must somehow obtain the type of the expression - and that's what `decltype` is for.

Comment: What if `decltype(*iterator)` is a proxy and not a reference?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You mean like `vector<bool>::iterator`?  (*shudder*)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Then you're out of luck with this approach. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SFINAE on

```
decltype( **(T*)0 = std::move(**(T*)0) )
```

or (Xeo's preference)

```
decltype( *declval<T&>() = std::move(*declval<T&>()) )
```

which checks whether dereferencing the iterator gives you something assignable.  Not perfect, if the element type of the collection isn't assignable, but then what good would it be to have a non-`const_iterator` anyway?

Don't test for `const_iterator`, test for the operation your algorithm actually needs.

Comment: For the love of everything, *use `*std::declval<T&>()`*.

Comment: @Xeo: Why?  It's about 20 extra characters for what benefit?

Comment: The benefit is for the love of everything

Comment: Well I don't love everything.  Some things (or ideas) are too horrible to love.

Comment: It doesn't lead to the false thinking of nullpointer-dereferencing (even if that doesn't actually happen), is much clearer, and people will know what it does.

Comment: @Xeo: People who don't understand "unevaluated context" certainly don't understand SFINAE.

Comment: @BenVoigt: This would make the SFINAE constraint a bit more complicated though, wouldn't it? (I mean, no matter whether `std::declval` is being used or not)

Comment: @Andy: My point is, the test requested in the question is useless for any actual algorithm.  Do you need to assign?  Devise an SFINAE test.  Call a non-const member function?  Use SFINAE on that.  Just having an iterator that isn't a `const_iterator` doesn't necessarily make the algorithm work.

Comment: OK, I honestly prefer a constraint of the type "*I want something that satisfies the requirements of this concept*" rather than "*I want something that lets me do this and this operation*", but I guess that's a matter of taste